# <svg> element string to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Hi I am given a room object with an image id which I fetch and am returned the following

```html
<svg id="Ebene_1" style={{"enableBackground":"new 0 0 32 32"}} version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" xmlSpace="preserve">
 <path d="M17.1,27h-10v-0.5c2.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-3.5h5.5c0,2.5,0,3.5,2.3,3.5V27z M30,6v20c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1H18c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4H3&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V9c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1l14,0V6c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1l11,0C29.6,5,30,5.4,30,6z M17,20h3v-9v-1h-1h-2H4v10H17z M24.8,22.5&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;c0-0.7-0.6-1.2-1.2-1.2s-1.2,0.6-1.2,1.2s0.6,1.2,1.2,1.2S24.8,23.2,24.8,22.5z M28,10h-6v1h6V10z M28,8h-7c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1h6V8z"/>
</svg>
```

**If I insert the returned string manually as follows into a react component (adding width and height)** then the component works fine.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


import React, { Component } from "react";

class LoxIcon extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <svg width ={'200'} height ={'200'}id= "Ebene_1" style={{"enableBackground":"new 0 0 32 32"}} version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" xmlSpace="preserve">
                 <path d="M17.1,27h-10v-0.5c2.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-3.5h5.5c0,2.5,0,3.5,2.3,3.5V27z M30,6v20c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1H18c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4H3&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1V9c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1l14,0V6c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1l11,0C29.6,5,30,5.4,30,6z M17,20h3v-9v-1h-1h-2H4v10H17z M24.8,22.5&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;c0-0.7-0.6-1.2-1.2-1.2s-1.2,0.6-1.2,1.2s0.6,1.2,1.2,1.2S24.8,23.2,24.8,22.5z M28,10h-6v1h6V10z M28,8h-7c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1h6V8z"/>
            </svg>
        )
    }
}  
export default LoxIcon;
```

Given that this  element is given to me dynamically how can I render it when I pass the data to the component via props, something like

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LoxIcon extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
                {this.props.svg}
   }        
  }
}  
export default LoxIcon;
```

I have tried  react-inlinesvg and reactSvg npm modules but both require a file not a string

Comment: can you share how you are passing the value to `LoxIcon` ?

Comment: <Grid container className={classes.root} >
          <Grid item >
              <Grid container  alignItems={'center'}  justify="center"  spacing={16}>
                  {(this.props.roomsData) ? 
                      this.props.roomsData.map(room =>(<Grid key={room.uuid} item >
                          <Card >
                            <LoxIcon  svg ={room.svg}/>
                          </Card>
              </Grid>)) 
              : null}
            </Grid>
        </Grid>      
      </Grid>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are passing the string representation of the html, you have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set the inner html to set the svg although it is not advised as it exposes to cross site scripting, so you are better off looking for other alternatives such as setting the values as proper dom representation in the React component's render method. Just in case you want to use this method, you can try following:

```
class LoxIcon extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.svg }} />);
       }
    }
export default LoxIcon;
```

You can have further reading on `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

**Edit:**

As **JP4** has suggested, you can create svg object in each element of  `roomsData` array and pass that object as the props to `LoxIcon` as answered by **JP4**. So your component will be look like:

```
<Grid container className={classes.root} > 
    <Grid item > 
        <Grid container alignItems={'center'} justify="center" spacing={16}> 
        {(this.props.roomsData) ? this.props.roomsData.map(room => 
            (<Grid key={room.uuid} item > <Card > <LoxIcon svg={room.svgObject} /> </Card> </Grid>)) : null} 
        </Grid> 
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Your `svgObject` should be like:

```
{
    height: value,
    width: value.
.... followed by all the properties.
}
```

and your `LoxIcon` will be like

```
import React from 'react';

const LoxIcon = ({ svgObject }) => (<svg width ={svgObject.width} height ={svgObject.height} id={svgObject.id} ...{all the attributes of svgObject your want to set>
<path d={svgObject.path.d}/>
</svg>);

export default LoxIcon;
```

Comment: Thank you I did see the dangerouslySetInnerHTML method but as you suggest I rejected it. Given what I am handed, ie the initial string, is there enough info there to parse and manipulate it in either json or xml to produce props as JP4 , if so what would be the best way to achieve  this

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to pass the props of the svg element into your component. If your dynamic element is not always an svg you could create some conditional rendering checking that its an svg element.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class LoxIcon extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <svg width={this.props.svg.width} height={this.props.svg.height} id={this.props.svg.id} style={this.props.svg.id} version={this.props.svg.id} viewBox={this.props.svg.viewBox} xmlns={this.props.svg.xmlns} x={this.props.svg.x} y={this.props.svg.y} xmlSpace={this.props.svg.xmlSpace}>
                    <path d={this.props.svg.d}/>
            </svg>
        )
    }
}  
export default LoxIcon;
```

Comment: I can see what you are saying but I am not passing all the elements of the svg via props I am only passing a string representation. ie.  <svg id="Ebene_1" style={{"enableBackground":"new 0 0 32 32"}} version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" xmlSpace="preserve">
 <path d="M17.1,27h-10v-0.5c2.3,0,2.3-1,2.3-3.5h5.5c0,2.5,0,3.5,2.3,3.5V27z M30,6v20c0,0.6-0.4,1-1,1H18c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1v-4H3&#xD;&#x...……..blah blah
</svg>

Comment: Could you pull those properties (id, style, viewBox...) out of the string and then pass them as props?

Comment: I thinks that is what I am going to have to do, but dom and element string manipulation does not come naturally to me atm, still we all learn any pointers will help

Comment: You could use string.split() method to split the string and loop through finding the properties. You can pass in characters like space (which wont work as your properties have spaces like viewBox) or a regular expression to filter out what you want.